# How to "manually" apply your gradients in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, gradient, autograd

what would be the equivalent in Pytorch of the following in tensorflow, where `loss` is the calculated loss in the iteration of the network and `net` is the Neural Network.

```py
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:              
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, net.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, net.trainable_variables))
```

So, we compute our gradients for all the trainable variables in our network in accordance to the loss function. In the next line we apply the gradients via the optimizer. In the use case I have, this is the way to do it and it works fine.

Now, how would I do the same in Pytorch? I am aware of the "standard" way:

```py
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

That is however not applicable for me. So how can I apply the gradients "manually". Google doesn't help unfortunately, although I think it is probably a rather simple question.

Hope one of you can enlighten me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break the standard PyTorch way of doing updates; hopefully, that will clarify what you want.

In Pytorch, each NN parameter has a `.data` and `.grad` attribute. `.data` is ... the actual weight tensor, and `.grad` is the attribute that will hold the gradient. It is `None` if the gradient is not computed yet. With this knowledge, let's understand the update steps.

First, we do `optimizer.zero_grad()`. This zeros out or empties the `.grad` attribute. `.grad` may be `None` already if you never computed the gradients.

Next, we do `loss.backward()`. This is the backprop step that will compute and update each parameter's `.grad` attribute.

Once we have gradients, we want to update the weights with some rule (SGD, ADAM, etc.), and we do `optimizer.step()`. This will iterate over all the parameters and update the weights correctly using the compute `.grad` attributes.

So, now to apply gradients manually, you can replace the `optimizer.step()` with a `for` loop like the below:

```
for param in model.parameters():
    param.data = custom_rule(param.data, param.grad, learning_rate, **any_other_arguments)
```

and that should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, that is already quite helpful. I was missing the ```params.data``` part to overwrite the weights in a "manual" way. In the meantime, I have also been stumbling upon ```grads = torch.autograd.grad(outputs = loss, inputs = net.parameters() )``` to compute the gradients more individually.

Comment: Yes, `autograd.grad` is more versatile. It can compute grads for non-leaf nodes too. IIRC, `loss.backward` internally invokes that to compute the gradient for leaf nodes. But it also takes care of assigning to `.grad` attributes correctly.